# How can I create hierarchical bar chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, hierarchy, hierarchical

I wanted to use the [Sortable Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1584697) of Mike Bostock without it's transition property and sort the bars according to their lenght but I couldn't. I want the bars just like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663). without interactivity.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.bar rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar text {
  fill: white;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<script src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var index = d3.range(24),
    data = index.map(d3.random.normal(100, 10));

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(index)
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + y(i) + ")";      });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("width", x);

bar.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 6; })
    .attr("y", y.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d, i) { return i; });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom"));

//var sort = false;

    //setInterval(function() {

    //  if (sort = !sort) {
    //  index.sort(function(a, b) { return data[a] - data[b]; });
    //  } else {
    //  index = d3.range(24);
    //  }

    //  y.domain(index);

    //  bar.transition()
    //    .duration(750)
    //    .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 50; })
    //    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + y(i) + ")"; });

    //}, 5000);

var hierarchy = d3.layout.partition()
    .data(function(d) { return d.data; });

</script>
```

I removed the the code from `var sort = false;` part and added 
`var hierarchy =..` part but It's still not working. How can I make it?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: So all you want to do is remove the transition?

Comment: I have already removed the transition but I couldn't sort the bars hierarchically.

Comment: I don't see how the changes you've made relate to that. You would literally only need to remove the `.transition()..`, wouldn't you?

Comment: When transition is removed, bars are being sorted randomly. I would like to sort the bars according to their lenght. As the longest one will be at the top and shortest one will be at the bottom.
Could you please explain how can i modify the original code to obtain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following line to sort the values:

```
index.sort(function(a, b) { return data[b] - data[a]; });
```

Check out the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k9rcyeyo/

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonas. I am appreicated for the answer.